# separate the unique value by comma in the list in a dataframe

Tags: r, list, datatable

I have a data frame with a column of list type where some of the values in the column looks exactly like below (including the c ):

```
c("A",B","A","A")
```

I want to convert the column into character type by unlisting it with the unique values separated with comma like below;

```
A,B
```

Tried to unlist the column like below but not able to get the desired output

```
df$col = unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$col), ",")))
```

Comment: You're missing a quotation mark

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `paste0()` function to concatenate a vector of strings:

```
a <- c('A','B','A','A')
paste0(unique(a), collapse = ',')
[1] "A,B"
```